# Problems with <select> filter

Tags: c#, html, razor

i coded an select filter for my website:

Filter

```
        <div class="row">

                <select class="event-type-select" id="selection" >
                    <optgroup label="categorygroup1">
                        <option value="category1">category1</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="categorygroup2">
                        <option value="category2">category2n</option>
                        <option value="category3">category3</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="categorygroup3">
                        <option value="category4">category4</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> filter </button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

before selecting anything in the "selection-window" on the website you read "category1". i guess thats default(?). 
but if i selected a category (and that works: you can read in the "selection-window" e.g. category3) and then click on the "filter"-button the website refreshes but in the "selection-window" you again read "category1" and not the selected category e.g "category3". i guess the selection doesn't work right.

how can i solve this that when clicking the button you still read your selected category?

also i want to display the selected option on a different part of the website.

my current code for this:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var m = document.getElementById("selection").value;}
        document.write(m);

    </script>
```

that as well doesn't work.

i hope you can understand what i mean, my english is pretty bad. sorry for that.

Comment: When you refresh the page the select show you the default value. This is normal behaviour. You can change the default value. You should also put the call to a function that show you the value in you button.

Comment: @Fabio_MO so the selection-works: "category3" is the selected option, even if "category1" is read in the selection-window. but i would need to change the default value to the from the user selected value? but "document.write(m)" still doesn't display my selected value

Answer (score 0):

The script has an error, you should use a function:

```js
            function test()
            {
                var m = document.getElementById("selection").value;
                alert(m);
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">

            <select id="selection" class="event-type-select">
                <optgroup label="categorygroup1">
                    <option value="category1">category1</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="categorygroup2">
                    <option value="category2" selected="selected">category2n</option> <!-- with selected="selected" you set the default -->
                    <option value="category3">category3</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="categorygroup3">
                    <option value="category4">category4</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="test()"> filter </button>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the question essentially contains 2 questions packed into one, don't do that.

Second, you are simply missing the preselection of the `<select>` field.

> the selection doesn't work

When submitting a form the values are sent to the server. The server processes the values and renders the page again. Therefore you have to adjust the rendering according to the selected value. Lets say you simply pass the selected value to the view as string the view code could look like this:

```
@model string

...

<select class="event-type-select" id="selection" >
    <optgroup label="categorygroup1">
        <option value="category1" @if (Model == "category1") {<text>selected</text>}>category1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="categorygroup2">
        <option value="category2" @if (Model == "category2") {<text>selected</text>}>category2n</option>

    ...
</select>
```

> also i want to display the selected option on a different part of the website.

Then store the selection somewhere (e.g. a DB), retrieve the selected value before the *different part*  is rendered and simply output it in the *different part*.